# how to invoke unsecured proxy while using spring security annotations?

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security annotations in my project. There are scenarios when i want to invoke security-less version of the annotated object. Spring by default creates a security-enabled proxy of the annotated object and uses it for autowiring in the code, is there any way that i can achieve this using spring ?
  An obvious way to do this would be to manually create proxy classes corresponding to each class for which i want this feature have those methods annotated and the implementation of these methods just delegate it to the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

As an option in a case of JDK proxies you can get actual bean at runtime:

```
MyBean proxy;    
if(AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy)) {
    MyBean actualInstance = (MyBean) ((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget()
}

actualInstance.doSomethingSecured(); // no advice related to this method will be called
// so your security annotation will be ignored (transactions, cache, and everething that requires AOP too...)
```

But from architectural point of view approach with manual proxies looks less error phrone (except if you absolutely sure that you do not need security and all another possible aspects too).

You can improve readability using generics:

```
MyBean actualInstance = extractProxyTarget(proxy, proxy.getClass());
actualInstance.doSomethingSecured();
```